# Python 2.7 trying to iterate file with usernames and passwords, unable to get data properly

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

I am using Python 2.7 and I have a text file exactly in this format starting like this:

```
Username: JohnDoe
Password: JohnsPass
------------------------
Username: Bob
Password: BobsPass
------------------------
```

It starts the same way you see above and ends the same way as you see.

I have tried the following to get the data in either a dictionary/list so I can import it into mysql.

```
thefile = open("theaccounts.txt","r")

myAcctList=[]
for line in thefile:
    myAcctList.append(line)

thefile.close()
```

Which shows me:

```
['Username: JohnDoe\n',
 'Password: JohnsPass\n',
 '------------------------\n',
 'Username: Bob\n',
 'Password: BobsPass\n',
 '------------------------\n']
```

I have been trying to get the username/password like so:

```
for userinfo in myAcctList:
    if userinfo.startswith('-------------'):
        pass
    else:
        print userinfo
```

It shows me:

```
Username: JohnDoe

Password: JohnsPass

Username: Bob

Password: BobsPass
```

How can I get this to be on one line or a dictionary even so I can import these into mysql DB?  I have tried various things but, they all either error out or it doubles the print out showing the username twice and the password from the previous username as the password.

Is there some way I can do:

```
print "Username is: %s and password is: %s" % (usernameis,passwordis)
```

As I would like to set the variable to place into the mysql record in one go, instead of matching the username and then inserting the password.

Please provide suggestions or solutions I have been trying to figure this out and really haven't been able to get it right.  Thanks for all input it is greatly appreciated!

**Update:**

I modified what you showed me and came up with this:

```
cur_user={}
countlogins=0
for userinfo in myAcctList:
    if userinfo.startswith('------------------------'):
        pass
    else:
        forusername=userinfo.split(':')
        print "I see index 0 as: %s" % forusername[0]
        print "I see index 1 as: %s" % forusername[1]
        cur_user[forusername[0]] = forusername[1].strip()
        print cur_user
        time.sleep(3) #just so I could see the top of the list
```

This is closer but, it still does some weird doubling up showing the username twice and showing the password for the previous line then the password it should be. It also only shows me the username when it hits the first line (I am guessing because it has not iterated to the 2nd line yet).

Print out is like so:

```
I see index 0 as: Username
I see index 1 as:  JohnDoe

{'Username': 'JohnDoe'}
I see index 0 as: Password
I see index 1 as:  JohnPass

{'Username': 'JohnDoe', 'Password': 'JohnPass'}
I see index 0 as: Username
I see index 1 as:  BobTheUser

{'Username': 'BobTheUser', 'Password': 'JohnPass'}
I see index 0 as: Password
I see index 1 as:  BobsPass

{'Username': 'BobTheUser', 'Password': 'BobsPass'}
I see index 0 as: Username
I see index 1 as:  ThisOtherUser

{'Username': 'ThisOtherUser', 'Password': 'BobsPass'}
I counted 5 logins
I see index 0 as: Password
I see index 1 as:  ThisOtherUserPass

{'Username': 'ThisOtherUser', 'Password': 'ThisOtherUserPass'}
I see index 0 as: Username
I see index 1 as:  YetOneMore
```

I cannot figure out why it's doubling up like that or why it takes it the 2nd go round to get the info right. This will prevent (if I'm not mistaken) proper insertion into mysql db. I would like to get it just telling me once what I need to know so that I can know it will insert the proper info.

Thanks for your time and assistance!

**2nd Update:**

I also tried:

```
theFile = open("theaccounts.txt","r")
users = []
cur_user = {}
for line in theFile:
    if line.startswith('------'):
        users.append(cur_user)
        cur_user = {}
    else:
        fields = ':'.split(line)
        cur_user[fields[0]] = fields[1].strip()
theFile.close()
```

Which gives me an error:

```
---> 10         cur_user[fields[0]] = fields[1].strip()
     11 theFile.close()

IndexError: list index out of range
```

So I then tried:

```
theFile = open("theaccounts.txt","r")
users = []
cur_user = {}
for line in theFile:
    if line.startswith('------'):
        users.append(cur_user)
        cur_user = {}
    else:
        fields = ':'.split(line)
        try:
            cur_user[fields[0]] = fields[1].strip()
            print cur_user
        except:
            pass
theFile.close()
```

Which only gave me:

```
[{},
 {},
 {},
 {},
 {},
 {},
 {},
 {}]
```

Please help me get this sorted it's really not making sense to me why it's so hard.

**3rd Update:**

Ok got it figured out!  Here is the final result for anyone else who might be needing to do this or gets in trouble:

```
countlogins=0
theFile = open("theaccounts.txt","r")
myAcctList=[]
cur_user={}
for line in theFile:
    if line.startswith('------'):
        countlogins=countlogins+1
        print cur_user
        myAcctList.append(line)
        cur_user={}
    else:
        forusername=line.split(':')
        cur_user[forusername[0]] = forusername[1].strip()
theFile.close()
print "I counted %s logins" % countlogins
```

I did the extra count at the end to verify it matched with what I was told.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Split the line using `:` as the delimiter. Then use the first part as the key in a dictionary, and the second part as the value. When you get to the `----` line, add the dictionary to your list.

Comment: I understand what you're saying I just don't understand how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the line using : as the delimiter. Then use the first part as the key in a dictionary, and the second part as the value. When you get to the ---- line, add the dictionary to your list.

```
users = []
cur_user = {}
for line in theFile:
    if line.startswith('------'):
        users.append(cur_user)
        cur_user = {}
    else:
        fields = line.split(':')
        cur_user[fields[0]] = fields[1].strip()
```

In your first update, the doubling up is happening because you're using the same `cur_user` dictionary for everything. So when you read the second username, you're just overwriting the username of that dictionary, not starting a new one. That's why my answer reassigns `cur_user = {}` after it adds the current user to the `users` list.

It takes two steps to get both the username and password into the dictionary, because when you read the first line of the file you haven't yet read the first password. Since you're printing the dictionary after each line, you see this partial result after the first line. You shouldn't try to add to the database until you get to the `-----` separator line, that's how you know you have both fields.

Comment: I was unsuccessful with several things I tried from your example.  I basically got the same as before with the doubling, then I tried to use directly what you showed and it didn't produce the desired results.

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain what you're seeing in your first update.

Comment: I think I am understanding better now.  The only thing is that now what it does is print out like this:                                                                                                                {'Username': 'JohnDoe'}  #How do I skip this?
{'Username': 'JohnDoe', 'Password': 'JohnsPass'}                                                                                                                                                                                                      I tried putting in an "if not cur_user['Password']: pass" to have it skip that, but it fails.

Comment: Specifically it fails saying "KeyError: 'Password'" which I know isn't there because I'm trying to pass it and get to the info I need.  Where would I put the cur_user in my first update? (Just trying to learn as much as possible if you could point that out please).  Ok I see where to put it but, I'm getting the same thing with it showing the username then the username/password.  How do I get it to skip the username and show me just the username/password?  Also is there a better way that this info should be stored? Like a pickle or csv file?

Comment: Ok I figured it out!  I added an "if len(cur_user)==2:" and I see exactly what I'm looking for.  Thank you so very much for helping me out!  If you have any suggested reading please advise.  I will mark this as completed, thanks again!!

Comment: Why don't you just put the `print` statement in the `if line.startwith('----')` block?

Comment: Oh wow you are right, that's even easier, cleaner and faster.  For some reason I am having huge brain farts on this.  I will correct the solution up top to your better one.